# Azure Policy allowed resource types with a like/match pattern

Tags: azure, policies

In the Azure Policy "allowed resource type" you can supply an array of resource types. When I want to allow SQL Elastic pool I need also to include all the subtypes of SQL Elastic pool.

I would like to use:

```
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/*'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticPools/advisors/*'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/elasticpool/advisors/*'
'microsoft.web/serverfarms/*
'microsoft.web/sites/*
```

But this doesn't work.

We now use:

```
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticPools/advisors'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/advisors/createindex'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/advisors/dbparameterization'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/advisors/defragmentindex'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/advisors/dropindex'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/advisors/forcelastgoodplan'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/elasticpool/advisors/createindex'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/elasticpool/advisors/dbparameterization'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/elasticpool/advisors/defragmentindex'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/elasticpool/advisors/dropindex'
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/elasticpool/advisors/forcelastgoodplan'
'Microsoft.Web/sites/config'
'Microsoft.Web/sites/...'
```

Policy we use is:

```
{
  "if": {
    "not": {
      "field": "type",
      "in": "[parameters('listOfResourceTypesAllowed')]"
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "[parameters('Effect')]"
  }
}
```

Policy parameter:

```
{
  "listOfResourceTypesAllowed": {
    "type": "array",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Allowed resource types",
      "description": "The list of resource types that can be deployed.",
      "strongType": "resourceTypes"
    }
  },
  "Effect": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "The effect of the policy."
    }
  }
}
```

Question is it possible to use wildcards or something like that?

Comment: try this: `"like": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/*"`

Comment: Thank you for your response. When using like and saving the definition it will give the following error:

Evaluation result of language expression '[parameters('listOfResourceTypesAllowed')]' is type 'Array', expected type is 'String'.'."}}

Comment: yeah, you need to edit your parameter definition, it must be a string, not an array and its value should be `Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools/*`.

Comment: Ok. I was not clear in mine question. I also wants in the same policy that for example HybridConnection is allowed and other resource types like websites, etc.

Comment: i dont think that will work with `like`, `in` doesnt support wildcards, you can always create more entries

Answer (score 0):

So you can only use wildcards with `like` or `notLike` conditions.

> When using the like and notLike conditions, you provide a wildcard * in the value. The value shouldn't have more than one wildcard *.
> [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#conditions:%7E:text=When%20using%20the%20like%20and%20notLike%20conditions%2C%20you%20provide%20a%20wildcard%20*%20in%20the%20value.%20The%20value%20shouldn%27t%20have%20more%20than%20one%20wildcard%20*.)

This works for me, im sure you could create the inverse easily enough.

```
{
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "type",
            "like": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts*"
          }
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "type",
            "like": "Microsoft.Resources/storageAccounts*"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  }
}
```

This will not allow storage accounts to be created.

Finding out the field types is a whole thing...

I've figured out a little one-liner which will create the JSON for you.
It will create about 1500 lines of JSON, you can just remove what you don't want.

```
az provider list | jq '[ .[].namespace + "/*" ] | unique | sort | [.[] | { "not" : { "field" : "type", "like": . } }]'
```

Whats interesting in my example is that `Microsoft.Resources` wasnt enough to stop storage accounts, i also needed `Microsoft.Storage`.